# python Notebook: Changing the written file

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help me guys see this problem. The tool I am trying to submit my task is called viope.com ,a self study environment, and it sometimes makes mistakes when it checks your code. My code seems to work fine for the first round but I don't understand why it is not printing when you select 1 for the second round, it seems to capture the change of the file name.  **Task** Also the other continuous project, the notebook, has relied on user actions in the sense that it would have broken down if the user had decided to read the file without writing anything to it. In this exercise we fix this, and add the possiblity of changing the used notebook file while the program is running.

First of all, make the program start by checking if there is a file "notebook.txt" and create one if there is none. If this has to be done, also inform the user with the warning "No default notebook was found, created one.".

When this feature works, add a fourth selection to the notebook, "(4) Change the notebook". If the user selects this option, the user is prompted for a new file "Give the name of the new file: ". If there is an existing file, it is opened and loaded into the notebook program, while the old notebook file is closed. If the new notebook file does not exist, the system informs the user "No notebook with that name detected, created one." and makes a new file. Also add a note of the used notebook file to the main menu, "Now using file [filename]".**The correct output should look like:**

```
>>> 

No default notebook was found, created one.

Now using file notebook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 2

Write a new note: Buy milk.

Now using file notebook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 4

Give the name of the new file: otherbook.txt

No notebook with that name detected, created one.

Now using file otherbook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 2

Write a new note: Buy pineapples.

Now using file otherbook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 4

Give the name of the new file: notebook.txt

Now using file notebook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 1

Buy milk.:::12:05:23 04/25/11



Now using file notebook.txt

(1) Read the notebook

(2) Add note

(3) Empty the notebook

(4) Change the notebook

(5) Quit



Please select one: 5

Notebook shutting down, thank you.

>>>
```

**my code:**

```
import time
try:
    f=open("notebook.txt","r")

    print("Now using file",f.name)
except Exception:
    print("No default notebook was found, created one.")
    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
    print("Now using file",mf.name)

mf="notebook.txt"    
promptForNumbers = True
while True:
    if promptForNumbers:
        print("(1) Read the notebook\n(2) Add note\n(3) Empty the notebook\n(4) Change the notebook\n(5) Quit\n")
        selection=int(input("Please select one: "))

    if selection==1:
        handle = open(mf,"r")
        filetext = handle.read()

        print(filetext)
        print("Now using file",handle.name)
    elif selection==2:
        filetext=input("Write a new note: ")

        myfile= open(mf, "w")
        myfile.write(filetext)
        myfile.write(":::")
        myfile.write(time.strftime("%X %x"))
        print("Now using file",myfile.name ) 

    elif selection==3:
        readfile = open(mf,"w")
        readfile.close()
        print("Notes deleted.")
    elif selection == 4:
        mf=input("Give the name of the new file: ")

        try:

            f=open(mf)
            filetext= f.read()
            print("Now using file",f.name)

        except Exception:

            print("No notebook with that name detected, created one.")
            x=open(mf,"w")

            print("Now using file",x.name )
        else:
            f.close
            promptForNumbers = True
    elif selection==5:
        print("Notebook shutting down, thank you.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect selection")
```

**my code's output:**

```
# python3.2 ohjelma.py 
No default notebook was found, created one.
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  2
Write a new note:  Buy milk.
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  4
Give the name of the new file:  otherbook.txt
No notebook with that name detected, created one.
Now using file otherbook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  2
Write a new note:  Buy pineapples.
Now using file otherbook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  4
Give the name of the new file:  notebook.txt
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  1
Buy milk.:::21:11:24 11/04/11
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  5
Notebook shutting down, thank you.
# python3.2 ohjelma.py 
No default notebook was found, created one.
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  2
Write a new note:  Buy pineapples.
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  4
Give the name of the new file:  otherbook.txt
No notebook with that name detected, created one.
Now using file otherbook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  1

Now using file otherbook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  4
Give the name of the new file:  notebook.txt
Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  1

Now using file notebook.txt
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Change the notebook
(5) Quit

Please select one:  5
Notebook shutting down, thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# python3.2 ohjelma.py 
No default notebook was found, created one.
Now using file notebook.txt
```

The way your code is written, if it does not find the notebook.txt file, it creates one, so even if it was there but not found correctly, it is now going to be over-written with a blank file. This is done here:

```
try:
    f=open("notebook.txt","r")

    print("Now using file",f.name)
except Exception:
    print("No default notebook was found, created one.")
    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
    print("Now using file",mf.name)
```

Are you doing something to change the file between runs of the program? The way you handle the Exception obscures any useful error messages. I would suggest changing this to:

```
try:
    f=open("notebook.txt","r")

    print("Now using file",f.name)
except IOError as e:
    print("IOErorr: ",e.strerror)
    print("No default notebook was found, created one.")
    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
    print("Now using file",mf.name)
```

Run it with that change and see what the problem is finding the notebook.txt you created in the previous run!

A few other things:

1) Your error-checking for wrong inputs doesn't handle the case where a user enters non-numerals.

2) You have an issue where you have a variable "mf" that can be referring either to a string or a file object, depending on where you are in the execution. Maybe not a problem, but definitely confusing.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for your time trying to help me. I have edited the question by adding the whole thing in case you want to see what the task is requiring me to accomplish. The way I understood the question is that the first error exception handling is a one time thing and I think that is why I put it outside the while loop.